# libxml2 get xsd validation errors

Tags: c, validation, xsd, libxml2

I'm using xmlTextReader to process large xml files. Now i need to validate the instance against an xsd schema. The api from libxml2 is a little bit confusing, how this is done.

With my approach, im getting the validation errors in the schemaParseErrorHandler function, but without any line numbers or column numbers.
How can i get these informations?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>
#include <libxml/encoding.h>
#include <libxml/xmlwriter.h>

static void schemaParseErrorHandler(void *arg, xmlErrorPtr error)
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Error at line %d, column %d\n%s",
        error->line, error->int2, error->message);

    *((bool*)arg) = true;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    xmlInitParser();

    xmlSchemaPtr schema = NULL;
    xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr schema_parser_ctxt = NULL;

    int has_schema_errors = 0;
    int ret = -1;

    xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr valid_ctxt = NULL;
    if ((schema_parser_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt("example.xsd")))
    {
        schema = xmlSchemaParse(schema_parser_ctxt);
        xmlSchemaFreeParserCtxt(schema_parser_ctxt);

        if (schema)
        {
            valid_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(schema);
        }
    }

    xmlTextReaderPtr reader = NULL;
    reader = xmlReaderForFile(filename, RPCXmlStream::STD_ENCODING, 0);

    if (reader != NULL)
    {
        if (valid_ctxt)
        {
            xmlTextReaderSchemaValidateCtxt(reader, valid_ctxt, 0);
            xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors(valid_ctxt, schemaParseErrorHandler, &has_schema_errors);
        }

        ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);

        while (ret == 1 && !has_schema_errors)
        {
            //... procesing informations
            ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        }
    }

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        xmlErrorPtr err = xmlGetLastError();

        TRACE("%s: failed to parse in line %d, col %d. Error %d: %s\n",
            err->file,
            err->line,
            err->int2,
            err->code,
            err->message);
    }

    xmlFreeTextReader(reader);
    xmlCleanupParser();     

    return 0;
}
```

Another try was to use the function 
`xmlTextReaderSchemaValidate(reader, "example.xsd");`
instead of creating an xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt, but than the programm is crashing on the first call to `xmlTextReaderRead`.

So how is validation done right, so that the error informations includes line and column numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your questions got me thinking and when I looked in the [libxml2 documentation](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html#xmlError),

```
Structure xmlError
struct _xmlError {
    int domain  : What part of the library raised this er
    int code    : The error code, e.g. an xmlParserError
    char *  message : human-readable informative error messag
    xmlErrorLevel   level   : how consequent is the error
    char *  file    : the filename
    int line    : the line number if available
    char *  str1    : extra string information
    char *  str2    : extra string information
    char *  str3    : extra string information
    int int1    : extra number information
    int int2    : error column # or 0 if N/A (todo: renam
    void *  ctxt    : the parser context if available
    void *  node    : the node in the tree
}
```

where we can clearly see that the `xmlErrorPtr` which is returned by the function `xmlGetLastError()` clearly contains information about the filename and the line number and the column number.

```
    char *  file    : the filename
    int line    : the line number if available
    ...
    int int2    : error column
```

So to test if this was possible or not, here is the code that I used (basically your code with minor changes to make it run on my system):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>
#include <libxml/encoding.h>
#include <libxml/xmlwriter.h>

static void schemaParseErrorHandler(void *arg, xmlErrorPtr error)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error at line %d, column %d\n%s", error->line, error->int2, error->message);
    *((bool*)arg) = true;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    xmlInitParser();
    xmlSchemaPtr schema = NULL;
    xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr schema_parser_ctxt = NULL;
    int has_schema_errors = 0;
    int ret = -1;
    xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr valid_ctxt = NULL;
    if ((schema_parser_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt("/home/junglefox/shiporder.xsd")))
    {
        schema = xmlSchemaParse(schema_parser_ctxt);
        xmlSchemaFreeParserCtxt(schema_parser_ctxt);
        if (schema)
        {
            valid_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(schema);
        }
    }
    xmlTextReaderPtr reader = NULL;
    const char* filename = "/home/junglefox/shiporder.xml";
    reader = xmlReaderForFile(filename, /*RPCXmlStream::STD_ENCODING,*/ NULL, 0);

    if (reader != NULL)
    {
        if (valid_ctxt)
        {
            xmlTextReaderSchemaValidateCtxt(reader, valid_ctxt, 0);
            xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors(valid_ctxt, schemaParseErrorHandler, &has_schema_errors);
        }
        ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        while (ret == 1 && !has_schema_errors)
        {
            //... procesing informations
            ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        }
    }

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        xmlErrorPtr err = xmlGetLastError();
        fprintf(stdout, "%s: failed to parse in line %d, col %d. Error %d: %s\n",
                err->file,
                err->line,
                err->int2,
                err->code,
                err->message);
    }
    xmlFreeTextReader(reader);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return 0;
}
```

where, the *shiporder.xml* and *shiporder.xsd* used in that program were copied from the [url](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp) and saved locally.

I compiled and ran the code like this:

```
junglefox@ubuntu:~$ gcc -o test_xsd main.c -I/usr/include/libxml2/ -lxml2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
junglefox@ubuntu:~$ ./test_xsd
junglefox@ubuntu:~$
```

The output this time was nothing. As it should be as there were no errors.

If however now I make an intentional error in the *shiporder.xml* file, as shown below:

- Here is the *partial*-snippet from the buggy *shiporder.xml*:

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  ...
      <item>
          <title>Hide your heart</title>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
          price>9.90</price>
        </item>
      </shiporder>`
- Notice the missing `<` before `price`!

Now I run the program again,

```
junglefox@ubuntu:~$ ./test_xsd 
Error at line 22, column 0
Element 'item': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
```

which answers your question(s):

> With my approach, im getting the validation errors in the schemaParseErrorHandler function, but without any line numbers or column numbers. How can i get these informations?

and,

> So how is validation done right, so that the error informations includes line and column numbers?

as the output clearly shows the **line number 22** and **column 0**, where there was an unexpected `empty space` due to the missing `<`.

Comment: Interesting, i'm getting no line nor clumn number (its always 0). Maybe my version of libxml2 is outdated. I'm using version 2.7.8, which version is yours?

Comment: Also 2.7.8 `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 10  2015 /usr/lib/libxml2.so -> libxml2.so.2.7.8`

Comment: Did you test with my code (there are some minor changes) and my sample *.xsd and *.xml files?

Comment: Yes, i took your code and your files and im getting the right parser message, but err->line and err->int2 are 0.

Comment: Then it cannot be something with the code, because the code works (at least on my system). I am running on an Ubuntu 18.04 and compiled with gcc 7.3.0, by the way. **What did you cahnge in the shiporder.xml file to produce an error?**, or you could share the **modified shiporder.xml** somehow. Maybe I could repeat the test on my side, if it shows the same or something different.

Comment: I am running an linux mint which based on ubuntu 18.04 also with gcc 7.3.0. I've made the same changes as you do, removing the opening < before price. Now i have updated libxml2 to version 2.9.3 and now i'am getting line informations. So the reason was my libxml2 it seems.